# Android - UsageStats getTotalTimeInForeground doesn't update current foreground app

Tags: android, foreground-service, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

I'm running a foreground service which samples the user's app usage in a timely manner.

I noticed a weird behavior of the `UsageStats getTotalTimeInForeground(..)` function - it seems that the stats are not updated for the currently foreground application until it goes to the background.

Code:

```
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
Map<String, UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, 0, System.currentTimeMillis());
long totalTimeUsageInMillis = queryUsageStats.get("com.sample.app").
    getTotalTimeInForeground();
```

After each iteration - `totalTimeUsageInMillis` is not affected while the `com.sample.app` is in the foreground.
Once I leave `com.sample.app` - my service gets the updated value

I can workaround this issue by keeping a counter for the currently-running (=foreground) app and add it to the result until the user switches app, but I prefer not to add overhead to the app.

The following screenshot was taken from a tester I built and shows 2 calls taken with 1 minute intervals: [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count app usage time while app is on foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677505/how-to-count-app-usage-time-while-app-is-on-foreground)