# How can i track the time user spend in a specific app using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I m developing an app that tells the users to install other apps from google play store and use them for 1 min, then they will win something in the app.
so:

- **is there a way that I can check if the user uses the app for 1 min or not?**
- or how to track the time spend by user in a specific app?

Comment: This answer discusses how to measure usage time while the app is in the foreground: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677505/how-to-count-app-usage-time-while-app-is-on-foreground

Answer (score 0):

You can try the stopwatch class to check the time when the users click your download link

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33636579)